# What is a matrix $A$ satisfying $A^m=I$ called?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

We have matrices that are idempotent $A^2=A$ or nilpotent $A^m=0$ for some $m$.

**Question:** What is a square matrix $A$ called for which $A^m=I$ for some integer $m$, where $I$ is the identity matrix?

Examples are rotations by $2\pi/m$.

Any reference would be appreciated!

Comment: I remember I already saw that question on this site but cannot find it. Formally it is a root of unity and as far as I know there is no standard name.

Comment: If $m$ is the least such positive integer, we might say $A$ is an element of order $m$ in the group $M_n(R)$ (where $R$ is the ring from which $A$ takes its elements). This is not exclusive to just matrices, however, but is used for groups in general (see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_an_element)). However, "order" in terms of a matrix may also reference its dimensions (see [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-we-find-the-order-of-a-matrix)), so there might be some confusion in using this term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such matrix $A$ is a matrix of finite order. You can find a classification in [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3219311) article for matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you - that is really helpful!